# Kubernetes: Have no access from EKS pod to RDS Postgres

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to setup kubernetes on AWS. For this I created an EKS cluster with 3 nodes (t2.small) according to official AWS tutorial. Then I want to run a pod with some app which communicates with Postgres (RDS in different VPC).

But unfortunately the app doesn't connect to the database.

What I have:

1. EKS cluster with its own VPC (CIDR: 192.168.0.0/16)
2. RDS (Postgres) with its own VPC (CIDR: 172.30.0.0/16)
3. Peering connection initiated from the RDS VPC to the EKS VPC
4. Route table for 3 public subnets of EKS cluster is updated: route with destination 172.30.0.0/16 and target — peer connection from the step #3 is added.
5. Route table for the RDS is updated: route with destination 192.168.0.0/16 and target — peer connection from the step #3 is added.
6. The RDS security group is updated, new inbound rule is added: all traffic from 192.168.0.0/16 is allowed

After all these steps I execute kubectl command:

```
kubectl exec -it my-pod-app-6vkgm nslookup rds-vpc.unique_id.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      rds-vpc.unique_id.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Address 1: 52.0.109.113 ec2-52-0-109-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Then I connect to one of the 3 nodes and execute a command:

```
getent hosts rds-vpc.unique_id.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
52.0.109.113    ec2-52-0-109-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com rds-vpc.unique_id.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

What I missed in EKS setup in order to have access from pods to RDS?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to fix the problem by `Service`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: rds-vpc.unique_id.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

So I created this service in EKS, and then tried to refer to `postgres-service` as DB URL instead of direct RDS host address.

This fix does not work :(

Comment: Have you tried to enable "dns propagation" in the peering connection? It looks like you are not getting the internally routable dns?

Comment: @donkeyx this is brilliant advice! This helped me :) So feel free to add this comment as a separate answer on this question and I'll upvote it and mark as a correct one!

Comment: @Alex Fruzenshtein, Have you fixed the issue by launching DNS propagation feature?

Comment: @mk_sta yep. In my case pods from the k8s cluster were not able to communicate with RDS just because "dns propagation" in the peering connection was not enables

Comment: Have you added entry to your route table for incoming traffic on postgres port ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried to enable "dns propagation" in the peering connection? It looks like you are not getting the internally routable dns. You can enable it by going into the setting for the peering connection and checking the box for dns propagation. I generally do this will all of the peering connections that I control.

Comment: Seems this DNS options are available once the PC is created.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been struggling for hours. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53433440/kubernetes-pod-unable-to-connect-to-rabbit-mq-instance-running-locally/53449625#53449625) may actually apply to your case, too.

It is about using [Services without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors). Look also into [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) Services.

Comment: thanks for the hint! I'll check it tomorrow when will get back to the normal internet again!

Comment: ExternalService doesn't work for me. Looks like I just mapped the original DB address to the Kubernetes Service abstraction :(