# Connection EKS Cluster to RDS Database Postgres on same VPC

Tags: node.js, amazon-rds, typeorm, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks

I have a deployment have container with node js with typeorm framework run on EKS, I want to connect to RDS Database (PostgreSQL) I already created on same VPC.
RDS Database is private access.

I have already configure security group with inbound rules following:
Type: Custom TCP Rule
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 22
Source: IP Address of machine

Because RDS Database on same VPC .. I've added inbound rules with following:
Type: PostgreSQL
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 22
Source: IP Address of machine

Then, I set HOST to the IP address source I've already set in inbound rules.
I also try to set HOST to connectivity endpoint.

But when I run kubectl logs pod-name, I got error

```
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT <my-ip>:5432
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either 
by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was 
not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI 
flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see 
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

I want to connect to my RDS Database with private from my EC2 instance on same VPC, how do I do that.
And best practice for connect into RDS Database from EC2 instance on EKS.

**UPDATE**

After Follow some step base on [Kubernetes: Have no access from EKS pod to RDS Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571908/kubernetes-have-no-access-from-eks-pod-to-rds-postgres?rq=1)

I create service with external name

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: rds-vpc.unique_id.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

I successfully connected to database..
However, whether to connect to a database with the same VPC must use a service?