# Cannot make connection to existing azure database via service construct

Tags: azure, spring-boot, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to map an existing azure mssql server to my kubernetes cluster as a service but it seems my application cannot connect to it.

Here's my config file, what am I doing wrong? Maybe it's because I'm doing this on a specific namespace?

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-database
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: mydb.database.windows.net
```

Then, in my application, I just use the following string:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:sqlserver://my-database:1433;databaseName=DATABASE_DEV
```

If I use the database host, mydb.database.windows.net, everything works fine so it is not a connection problem but rather something related to my service conf...

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to create [Service without a selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors), then an `Endpoints` object for the `Service`. Similar to my answer here:
[Kubernetes pod unable to connect to rabbit mq instance running locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53433440/kubernetes-pod-unable-to-connect-to-rabbit-mq-instance-running-locally/53449625#53449625)

Just disregard the talk about localhost...